# How to set cookies in the browser from the header sent from express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

app.js

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())



app.post('/getcookies', (req, res)=>{

    res.cookie('test', 'jwt', {expiresIn : "2h", httpOnly : false, secure : false, strict : "none"}).status(200).json({how : "done"});
})

app.listen(7000, ()=>{
    console.log("success...");
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfoO6.png)

i have made a request with postman but it is not showing any set-cookie header and so not setting cookies.
If i change method to get and visit **http://localhost:7000/getcookies** than the cookies are set in browser.
If i make a post request from **http://localhost:3000/** to **http://localhost:7000/getcookies** with a button click than also the cookies are not setting in browser. But in the network tab the set-cookie header is showing.
Please anyone help me to set the cookies from the express to the react app in the browser with a button click in post and get request.

Note : I am using axios to make request from react

Comment: Do you use fetch, axios or html form?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fetch, you need to set the option `credentials` to include. The following is an example:

```js
try {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/getcookies", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
  });

  const json = await res.json();
  console.log(json);
  // Don't worry, cookies are set :)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

With axios, same thing, but the option is called `withCredentials`

```js
try {
  const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:7000/getcookies", { withCredentials: true });

  // Don't worry, cookies are set :)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

If you are not using any of these two HTTP clients, then try to see if there is a similar option you could pass. Hope this helps!